# Terminating a while(cin >> s) loop. Accelerated C++

Tags: while-loop, cin, terminate, accelerated-c++

I almost sure this question had been ask, but after a long search I still can't find the answer. I extracted this piece of code from Accelerated C++, and I have a problem with terminating the `while` loop. Code is here:

```c
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

istream& read(istream& in, vector<double>& vec)
{
    cout << "start reading" << endl;
    if (in) {
        vec.clear();
        double x;
        while (in >> x) {
            cout << "x=" << x << endl;
            vec.push_back(x);
        }
        in.clear();
    }
    cout << "end reading" << endl;
    return in;
}

int main() {
    vector<double> vec;
    read(cin, vec);
    return 0;
}
```

I input `1 2 3 4 5` type EOF (Ctrl-D on MacOS) the program does not terminate. I can continue typing values into the vector:

```
start reading
1 2 3 4 5 x=1
x=2
x=3
x=4
x=5


5
x=5
6
x=6
7
x=7
```

The closest question I found here:
http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/beginner/49993/

Comment: Does it terminate when stdin comes from a file (as in `mypog < inputfile`)?

Comment: Also, there's a problem with your code: only the `cout` is inside the `while` loop, the `vec.push` is outside the loop, even though the indentation indicates that you intended it to be inside the loop (where it should be). Use curly braces around the two lines.

Comment: And if you run `cat` (without arguments) in the terminal, does it terminate when you press Ctrl-D?

Comment: About `cat` it works just with Ctrl-D. But I found the answer! Check it bellow. And thanks for the comment about curly braces... shame on me :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok the problem was that in mac I should do the following: press ctrl-D to signal and end to stdin, and then the enter key to return the buffer.
More: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/2361809

Comment: You might want to mention in your answer that the reason is that stdin is line-buffered: your program only gets input after a line s complete or the buffer is full (very long line).